# Showing a set is monotone class

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $\Omega$ is a set. Let $F_o$ be the field of subsets of $\Omega$.  Let $F=\sigma(F_o)$.

Consider $M$, the smallest monotone class containing all sets of $F_o$.

Fix $A\in M$.

Show $M_A=\{B\in M: A\cap B, A\cap B^c, A^c\cap B\in M\}$ is a monotone class.

*My Understanding:*

Consider a sequence of sets, $(B_n)\in M_A$ such that $B_n\uparrow B.$ Need to show $B\in M_A.$

Know by definition, for every $n$, it follows:

$A\cap B_n, A\cap B^c_n, A^c\cap B_n\in M$.

Consider the countable union of each case:

$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(A\cap B_n)=A\cap B.$

$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(A\cap B_n^c)=A\cap (\bigcup_n B^c)=A\cap (\bigcap_n B)^c=A\cap B_1\in M.$

$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(A^c\cap B_n)=A^c\cap B.$

How do I get to what I want to show? I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A \cap \bigcup_nB_n=\bigcup_n(A\cap B_n)$

Since $B$ are increasing,then $A \cap B_n$ are increasing and their union belongs to $M$ since $M$ is a monotone class.

Thus $A \cap B$ belongs to $M$ so $B$ belongs to $M$.

Do the same for sets of the form $A^c \cap B$

and for decreasing sequence of sets in both cases.

Now   for the sets of the form $B^c \cap A$

If $B_n$ are decreasing note that $B_n^c$ are increasing and $A \cap B_n^c$ are increasing.

If $B_n$ are increasing note that $B_n^c$ are decreasing and $A \cap B_n^c$ are decreasing.

Comment: Excellent thank you